# How to access Hololens accelerometer (IMU)?

Tags: accelerometer, hololens

I would like to access Accelerometer data from Microsoft Hololens. I have deployed on he Hololens the 'Accelerometer' sample from Windows-universal-samples-master (free source code in GitHub); but when I launch the app 'Accelerometer C# sample' on Hololens, it says : standard accelerometer not  found.
Anybody have a solution ?
Thanks

P.S The Research mode enabled in Windows Portal.